# Struct variable doesn't changed by assignment

Tags: c, struct, signed, bit-fields, twos-complement

```
struct st  
{  
    int a1 : 3;  
    int a2 : 2;  
    int a3 : 1;  
}

void main(void)
{
    x.a3 = -1;  

    if (x.a3 == -1) printf("TRUE\n");
    else printf("FALSE\n");

    x.a3 = 1;  
    if (x.a3 == 1) printf("TRUE\n");
    else printf("FALSE\n");  
}
```

In case, **'x.a3 = -1;'** First if is *TRUE*.
But, why **'x.a3 = 1'** doesn't changed in second if ? It's still x.a3 = -1.

And
If I type **'x.a3 = 1;'** in first if, it still x.a3 = = 1 !! It doesn't changed!

[Debug Result in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coXOy.png)

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid signature. the minimal signature is `int main(void)`. What is `x`? The code does not compile. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf As I read C11 5.1.2.2.1 2, "It shall be defined with a return type of int ...  or in some other implementation-defined manner." `void main(void)` is implementation-defined if it is valid, not certainly invalid.  I suppose it depends on the "or".  IAC, certainly not OP's key problem.

Comment: @chux: This is subject to interpretation. Let that apart, all full-size OS require an `int` result.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, a signed `1` bit variable can hold only two values, `-1` and `0` (Read about [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). It is not sufficient to hold a value of `1` (+`1`, to be exact).

To elaborate, while writing the assignment

```
 x.a3 = 1;
```

the value of integer constant `1` is stored into the memory location reserved for the member `a3`, but while accessing the variable, as per the signedness of the variable (maybe `signed` or `unsigned`, implementation defined behaviour, as per chapter §6.7.2/P5), the representation will be read from the memory.

The representation of a *stored* value of `1` in two's complement, will produce the result `-1` (as per MSB value), so a condition check with `== 1` will fail, always.

Comment: It is implementation defined whether plain `int` in a bit-field is a signed or unsigned value.  Almost everything about bit-fields is implementation defined, in fact.

Comment: @chux Thanks for correcting me, I missed the earlier comment somehow. updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because field `a3` is a 1 bit `int` (and therefore signed), it can only hold a value of 0 (if the bit is 0) or -1 (if the bit, which is the sign bit, is 1).  So when you attempt to assign the value 1, the representation of that value is stored, and that representation in the given datatype is -1.

Just because the value -1 in a 1-bit `int` would have the same representation as the value 1 in a 1-bit `unsigned int` doesn't mean they compare to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a3 : 1;
```

is a struct with a bit field which defines how much space to use to store the var. You are making a1 a one bit signed int, which can only hold the values -1 and 0. If you had intended a3 to hold the value 1, then the syntax you may have intended was int a3 = 1 then one of the many way to do that might look like this

```
struct st  
{  
    int a1 : 3;  
    int a2 : 2;  
    int a3 : 1;  
};


void main(void)
{
    struct st x = {1,2,3};
    x.a3 = -1;  

    if (x.a3 == -1) printf("TRUE\n");
    else printf("FALSE\n");

    x.a3 = 1;  
    if (x.a3 == 1) printf("TRUE\n");
    else printf("FALSE\n");  
}
```