# Why output of the below code is -1 and -2?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

Why output of the below code is -1 and -2, It should be 1 and 2, Right?

Also on a 64 bit server size of the below structure is 4 Bytes, It should be 8 Bytes right?

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct st
{
        int a:1;
        int b:2;
};
main()
{
        struct st obj={1,2};
        printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n",obj.a,obj.b);
        printf("Size of struct = %d\n",sizeof(obj));
}
```

Comment: you get the answer as `-1 and -2` or `-1 and 2`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh -1 and -2 Sir

Comment: "It should be 1 and 2, Right?" No, why do you think it should be like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile with all the warnings enabled, and read what your compiler says:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
main.c:7:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^
main.c:9:26: warning: implicit truncation from 'int' to bitfield changes value
      from 2 to -2 [-Wbitfield-constant-conversion]
        struct st obj={1,2};
                         ^
main.c:11:40: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
        printf("Size of struct = %d\n",sizeof(obj));
                                 ~~    ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                 %lu
3 warnings generated.
```

Recall, that

> a signed 1 bit variable can hold only two values, -1 and 0

as you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452788/struct-variable-doesnt-changed-by-assignment).

So if you use this struct instead:

```
struct st
{
        int a:2;
        int b:3;
};
```

you will get the desired output.

---

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18560011/2411320) gives a nice explanation as well.

Comment: You are welcome @Chirag, I updated my answer with a working struct, hope this will be enough for acceptance! :)

Comment: Yes, I am very much clear with this concept, Thanks for the help